# Play! Framework "Unexpected identifier" in string

Tags: string, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am retrieving a string from the messages file (a string resource file with key and values) and trying to store it in a javascript variable . It apparently contains characters that javascript does not like. How can I retrieve the string from  the messages file without having to edit all the strings in the messages file, to avoid the "Unexpected identifier" error message which kills the entire script? I tried adding quotes around:   "&{  'pages.'+_section+'.footnote.'+_page+'.html' }"  but it did not help...

crashes right here:

```
var sRefTxt =  "&{  'pages.'+_section+'.footnote.'+_page+'.html' }";
```

My Play! version is 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&{''}` syntax is a shortcut to load a message. It takes a string as a parameter. You cannot use variables in here.

Instead of using this syntax:

```
&{'message'}
```

You can use this:

```
${play.i18n.Messages.get('message')}
```

For your example, it would be:

```
${play.i18n.Messages.get('pages.'+_section+'.footnote.'+_page+'.html')}
```

Comment: Ha I actually just figured this out. Thanks though!